# Weird behavior of navigation bar when returning from a UISearchDisplay table

Tags: ios, uinavigationbar, uisearchdisplaycontroller, unwind-segue

I am puzzled by a behavior of my app when unwinding from a tabbar controller with a number of tableview featured with UISearchDisplay functionalities. If I unwind from any of the table views with the SearchDisplay hidden, the navigation bar on the top controller is correctly hidden; same if I do it on one of the controllers with the UISearchDisplay shown. Yet when I unwind the controller while the second table controller displays the UISearchDisplay, the navigation bar magically appears. What is really puzzling is that as far as the ViewDidAppear of the main controller is executed, the navigation bar remains hidden. Yet soon after it is resurrected. The code does not of course diverge when returning from one of the table controllers or the other. How could the dead controller set the navigation bar visibility in the main controller? Or what could be the reason of this behavior anyway?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed the issue by delaying the bidding of the navigation bar by a fraction of second by GCD.